# Using Easting And Northings As Spatial Data In SQL / Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssms, spatial

I have a database that has a lot of eastings and northings (X & Y) data, I'd like to be able to plot some of these positions on a map in Visual Studio 2010, everytime I try and do this I add the query into VS and it tells me none of the fields contain spatial data? How do I convert this data into data that VS recognises as spatial data? I really don't know anything about spatial data so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is presumably in a numeric format and not in a spatial one.

Try converting your data with a query like `SELECT GEOMETRY::Point(X, Y, 4152)`
With 4152 referencing the spatial reference id of NAD83, or your coordinate system.

These spatial reference ids can be found in `sys.spatial_reference_systems`, assuming you are using SQL SERVER 2012 or greater.